# How to use IEnumerable as a navigation property instead of IList

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, domain-driven-design, ienumerable

How to use `IEnumerable` as a navigation property, I don't want to expose a List for the client developer and give him extra distracted,undesirable functionalities like `Clear(),CopyTo()`.

So I did the following :

---

```
 private readonly List<WorkTime> _assignedWorkTimes;

 public virtual IEnumerable<WorkTime> AssignedWorkTimes { get => _assignedWorkTimes; }
```

But When I use `EF Power tool` to render the model I see no relationship between the two entities.

Note: I make a unidirectional relationship (based on `DDD` recommendations) with only a Foreign key in `Worktime` to facilitate the data operations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For creating one to many relationships the 'many' property must implement ICollection. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd468057(v=vs.100).

Or, in other words, what you want is not possible with EF6.